# Unittest for excisting NFT

Tags: solidity, unittesting, test, chai

I have build a contract (not yet deployed) that allows to check if the `msg.sender` holds a certain NFT:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/IERC721.sol";

contract Example {

  function walletHoldsToken() public view returns (bool) {
    return IERC721(0x1615600fE62ed38342F82eb9785029A2b1290DAF).balanceOf(msg.sender) > 0
  }

}
```

I want to create a test with `Hardhat` and `Chai` to check if the `msg.sender` holds a certain `NFT`.

So what I basically need is:

1. Populate the test environment for Chai to include am NFT of the certain address and add it to a signer.
2. Create a test that validates if the signer holds this NFT.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I think it's totally possible, you can impersonate anyone and fork the mainnet with hardhat

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the contract by using `ethers`

```
const erc721 = ethers.Contract(YOUR_NFT_ADDRESS, ERC721ABI, signer)
```

And you can test user holder nft or not:

```
expect(await erc721.balanceOf(userAddress)).to.not.equal(0)
```

In `hardhat` you can run tests specify network

```
npx hardhat test --network mainnet
```

Comment: Great!
Thank you!
I will try this out.